# How to Implement Shared Secret Key into the code using in-app purchase in iOS

Tags: ios

any one know about how to How to Implement Shared Secret Key into the code using in-app purchase in iOS than please help, I read this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW2) and generate `Shared Secret Key` in-app purchase but don't Know How to Implement Shared Secret key in to the Code any one have a answer for this question than help for this issue.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: Hey Buddy i just using store kit Framework Files method for the in-app purchase and i can't use any of the shared secret key over there. i found that ans in stackoverflow that no need to use shared secret key if you are using stokekit Frameworks methods.